# Scrivener customising the header and footer

Tags: style, scrivener

To my understanding you can only edit the header and footer through the compile settings. Here we can customise using tokens:-

```
<$compilegroup>
<$projecttitle> 
<$abbr_projecttitle> 
<$sectiontitle>  
<$p>
```

So on... What I would really like is to have facing pages which I have set up correctly and have headers such as:-

**Page number | Chapter 1 : Sub title**

Here is where it gets slightly complicated. I don't want this on my chapter headings. The options Scrivener gives are:-

1. No header on first page and pages following page breaks.
2. No header or footer on single pages.

**Problems**

Lets say I have a chapter description and it goes over one page, this invalidates number 2.

Page breaks, by using this the layout gets quite messy and the headings will appear as:-

**Page number | Chapter 1 : Chapter 1 Binder title**

If anyone can advise a possible solution, perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from Scrivener Staff:

I'm afraid that there are limits to how much headers and footers can be customised from within Scrivener itself and you've hit up against that. While Scrivener is capable of creating verso headers and footers (right and left), and it can create a different header/footer style for the "first pages" of the manuscript, it cannot create a separate header/footer for the first page of each chapter.

I'm afraid this level of customisation would have to be done by compiling to Word and making the changes there.

***Credits go to:***
**Jeff**

from

Literature and Latte Support

Answer (score 8):

Far be it from me to disagree with the Scrivener staff, but I have been doing this very thing with my PDF. Here's the basics of my setup.

- PDF output using `Printing` layout
- In the `Formatting` section, Level 1 folders are configured to always start on a recto page. (Under the `Section Layout` button, then `First Page` tab.)
- In the `Page Settings` section...

  - `Header and Footer` tab

    - My desired header and footer are typed in the center boxes
    - `No header on first page and pages following page breaks` is checked.
    - `No header or footer on single pages` is not checked.
  - `First Pages` tab

    - I put a single space in the header and footer center text boxes
    - `Different first page header/footer` is checked.
    - `Page numbers count first pages` is checked.
    - `Start regular header and footer` is set to Page 4.
  - `Facing Pages` tab

    - Same header and footer text from the first tab is in the center text boxes
    - `Use facing pages` is checked.

And here is how it comes out on mine...

Hope this helps.

[image: Chapter Headers]
[image: No Chapter Headers]

Comment: Hey @Josh thank you for taking the time to give a detailed answer and a solution. I will give this a go as soon as I get the chance. Thanks. +1